# Restoring an old MySQL backup

Tags: mysql, backup, phpmyadmin, mediawiki

I have a large file from 2007 containing a backup (as a SQL Script) of a MySQL Database. It's for an unknown version of MediaWiki.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.6.2-Debian-3sarge3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 29, 2007 at 12:42 PM
-- Server version: 4.0.24
-- PHP Version: 4.3.10-19
```

I've tried installing *mysql-5.5.8-win32* and *mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.31a-win32* but am getting syntax errors. Is there an easy way of making the old script compatible, or am I better of using an older version of MySQL? Are the dev tools still available for the older versions?

I am looking for the quickest simplest option as I only want to restore it to get hold of some old raw data, not to set it up fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be worth to actually showing the error.

But anyway, `SET sql_mode = MYSQL40` might help you if the syntax is really a problem. There might be issue with something what was not keyword before and now is, you would have to escape it in this case.

Comment: You won't get better answers without actually showing what is the problem.