# MySql wampserver restoring database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wampserver, mysql-error-2002

MySql version: 5.5.24

**NOTE:** *Everytime I copied the old "data" folder, MySql services stops and turn Wamp icon from green to orange.*

Solutions I've tried but no luck:

- [WAMP MySQL error 2002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748055/wamp-mysql-error-2002)
- [phpmyadmin 2002 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842450/phpmyadmin-2002-error)
- [Restoring old database in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650390/restoring-old-database-in-mysql)
- [Restoring an old MySQL backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500812/restoring-an-old-mysql-backup)

**etc..**

Before, I got an error #2002

> *The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)*

I did try searching and applied some of the solutions but still got no luck. I can't still access PhpMyadmin. I can see that instead of green, wampserver icon is **orange** because MySql is not running.

After couple of days, **I reinstall my wampserver (the same version) and phpmyadmin works**.. but as I copied mysql data folder and files (ibdata1, iblogfile0 and iblogfile1) and restarted the services I got back to my problem #2002.

**My Problem:**

*I want to create an sql dump of my database but I cannot access my phpmyadmin because MySql service is not running*

**Questions:**

1. How can I restore MySql database out from wampserver data to the new installation by just copying the necessary folders or files?
2. **If #1 is not possible**, is there a way to create a **sql dump** via console or anything without going to phpmyadmin?

**Note:**

- I have **full backup of the original folder wamp** before I reinstall the server.
- I have no old sql dump to restore.

**MySQL LOG:**

```
141209 21:54:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
141209 21:54:40 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
141209 21:54:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
141209 21:54:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
141209 21:54:40 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
141209 21:54:40 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141209 21:54:40 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 52664174
141209 21:54:40  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 56879679
141209 21:54:41  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 2383366, file name .\mysql-bin.000115
141209 21:54:42  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
141209 21:54:43  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 636 in file fut0lst.ic line 83
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
141209 21:54:43 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 56879679
InnoDB: Thread 5328 stopped in file ibuf0ibuf.c line 3165
```

Comment: Look at your Windows Event Viewer fo rerror message from MYSQL. If MYSQL fails before it can open its error log the errors are logged in there

Comment: @RiggsFolly .. I can't see no error in Windows Event for Mysql

Comment: If the wamp icon is orange because MySQL has not started, then there must be error messages in either the `mysql error log` and/or the `Windows Event Viewer`

Comment: @RiggsFolly .. added MySql logs

Comment: Well there you go, if you read the error it should be self explanitor. You have a corruption and I am guessing you are going to have to read the MYSQL manual to research a solution.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah..thank you.. I know that.. would you mind telling me where I should start? I've been working on this for 5 days already.. Lots of tutorials doesn't cover db corruption.. mostly restoring old db.. I can't run sql dump since mysql is not running.. please.. thnx

Comment: Start with [the page link in the error message](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) You have the old data folder so you can try any number of things and still be able to get back to here. I cannot help a great deal as I have not got the database to play with. It will be trial and error whoever attempts the recovery. _Still now you know the benefits of regular backups, especially of INNODB databases_ so its not been a total loss